# Why the pom for jsf-impl does not contain a dependency to jsf-api

Tags: maven, jsf-2, dependencies

I'm new to maven and there are something with dependencies that I'm not able to understand.
JSF implementation depends on JSF API, even though in the POM for the jsf impelmentation (ie: https://maven.java.net/index.html#nexus-search;quick~jsf-impl) I can't find any dependencies to the JSF api.
What am I missing here ?

Thank you.

Comment: http://javaserverfaces.java.net/download.html

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy The link recommends other dependencies (JSF API only, org.glassfish.javax.faces which bundles both API and implementation). But doesn't answer the question.